# How to load image from a website in android?

Tags: java, android

[This](http://www.bestandroidblog.com/android-phones/which-android-phone-will-take-the-title-of-the-best-android-phone-of-2012/) site contains more than one image. But in a webview I just want to load any one of these images. How to do it?

Comment: yes i tried and its fetching the image of a specific image url of that website, what to do if i dont know the image url?

Comment: So you want to randomly select one of those images?

Comment: yes, any image of that website, but the problem is i dont know the url of those. and the website may change anytime, I just want to know that is there anythig to do that will automatically find the image url of that website and shows any one?

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the image URL...once you get the URL you..use like this..this sample code will save the image in your mobile sd card..

```
String fileURL = "URL";
URL url = new URL(fileURL);
URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
conexion.connect();
int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/"+ filename);
byte data[] = new byte[1024];
long total = 0;
while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
total += count;
output.write(data, 0, count);
}
output.flush();
output.close();
input.close();
```

Comment: If i view the source then i can get the image url and the above code works fine but this website is not parmanent, is there any way to get the image url of any website?

Comment: the website i gave is an example, what to do if the website changes?

Comment: if you dont want your images to change..get the image and save it into your local/server and point to your local/server instead point to that website..

Comment: no, the image will be changed as well as the website, but i need a common program that will fetch image from any website

Comment: fetch what image.? you need to specify on where and what image to fetch.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest first get the source of the webpage in a buffered reader [example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-android-networking/index.html?ca=drs-) , then use regex to find all links of images or use any pattern matcher string to extract links of those images. Once you have done that download the images and then display them.